# applications communicate with the web service is an erp

Tags: rest, database-design, architecture, soa, erp

if in said soa is an architecture that allowed modularity?
I want to understand :

-can say a whole app to communicate with web service (service oriented architecture)?

-multi applications communicate with the web service is an erp?

Answer (score 0):

[ERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_resource_planning) is a totally different concern, it is concerned with the purpose of the application, not the design or architecture of the application.

Usually when you use a SOA architecture, you want to design each app so that it's communication with the web services is fairly isolated (as in a client dao layer).

Comment: in erp if we say that we used soa seen that we have multi purposes
else how to use soa term in erp

Comment: ERP has nothing to do with SOA.  ERP is Enterprise Resource Planning, SOA is generally Service Oriented Architecture.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is too big of a question.  Modularity is a broad topic, you should do some independent research.  SOA is a way to achieve modularity, but it has nothing to do with ERP.  You CAN use SOA to achieve modularity in ERP, you can also use object oriented design, onion architecture, and a dozen other methods.  All of this depends on things like your technology stack, your requirements, your personal knowledge, your team knowledge, etc.